# How do I prove - If matrix A is similar to matrix B and matrix C is similar to matrix D, then matrix A*C is similar to matrix B*D?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, similar-matrices

I am generally looking for solving two pairs of n*n matrices. Also, if the nth row of matrix A is in the mth row of matrix C then the nth row of matrix B will also be in the mth row of matrix D. I am providing an example just for reference -

[image]

Comment: Normally, on MathSE, we need to see what you have tried so far, and maybe what you are thinking. Can you edit your post to reflect any of that?

Comment: You won't be able to prove it.  It's not true.  Indeed, as one of the linked questions notes, there are $2 \times 2$ matrices $A \sim B$ with $AB \nsim BA$.

Comment: @PavanC. I have provided some extra details, please ignore the example. I know they are similar because I have simulated tons of matrices and their eigenvalue matches. I need to prove how. Thanks!

Comment: Your second sentence is confused. Your are suggesting a "permutation of rows" relation between $A$ and $C$, and also between $B$ and $D$. But in your example no such relation holds; there is instead another relation between $A$ and $B$, and also between $C$ and $D$, but it involves permutation of both rows _and_ columns (and not by the same permutation).

Comment: @TryHardGaming Thank you for sharing your work. As Robert and many others mentioned, this is not a true statement. But I wanted to see your work to see where you were going wrong. But I suppose you now have your answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement of your title is not even true for the very well behaved class of invertible diagonal matrices. Consider $A=\binom{1~~0}{0~~2}$ and $C=\binom{2~~0}{0~~1}$; these are clearly similar, so if what you say were true one should have that $AC$ and $AA=A^2$ are similar. But $AC=\binom{2~~0}{0~~2}=2I$ which is not similar to any matrix different from it, while  $A^2=\binom{1~~0}{0~~4}$.

Answer (score 0):

This is not true. E.g. consider
$$
A=D=\pmatrix{1&0\\ 1&0},\ B=C=\pmatrix{0&0\\ 1&1},\ AC=0,\ BD\ne0.
$$
This counterexample actually shows more, namely, even if $A$ is similar to $B$, $AB$ can be dissimilar to $BA$.

Comment: Actually, they are, I mentioned similar (not the same) if you find the eigenvalue of AC =  {0, multiplicity of 2} = BC where AC = [[0,0],[0,0]] and BC = [[0,0],[2,0]]

Comment: @TryHardGaming I don't understand your comment. First, you question is about the similarity between $AC$ and $BD$, not between $AC$ and $BC$. Second, since the zero matrix is only similar to itself, the zero matrix $AC$ in my answer is not similar to the nonzero matrix $BD$, although they have the same eigenvalues.